# Does the NET Framework communicate with Comodo servers?

Tags: c#, .net, security, firewall

I have a 3rd party .NET application that we're using internally, and every few days it communicates with one `ocsp.comodoca.com (178.255.83.1)`, a server thats run by the COMODO security services.

Does the .NET Framework internally communicate with such servers, for strongly-signed applications or something? I'm just asking because usually we deny such communication and everything works fine. But now we need to allow it for other reasons and I'm wondering exactly what is being tracked. (usage stats?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCSP is used for checking X.509 certificate status. This can happen if the application validates some certificates and this also happens when assemblies are Authenticode-signed (in which case the signature seems to be validated during loading).